# I am not able to get the details from $scope.notifications = response .data

Tags: angularjs, node.js

Hello I am having this code and is working perfectly, I want to get the  details of user details from *response.data*.
There are several objects in *response.data*. *userId* is one of them and I want to get the details of the user which is associated with '*userId*'
Can some one help me to extract the details of *userId* from response.data

```
$scope.notifications = [];
    $scope.getNotifications = function(){
        $http.get(baseUrl+'')
        .success(function (response) {
            $scope.notifications = response.data;
            alert($scope.notifications.userId);
        }).error(function(data, status){
            //$scope.isSending = false;
        });
    };
```

[image: This is detals inside my response.data]

Comment: Can you provide the request treatment in your question? You know, the code which you're using to return the info...

Comment: console.log(response.data) so that we can see what is being returned from your web call

Comment: Try this $scope.notifications = JSON.parse(response.data)

Comment: I'm trying to determine if userId is a string type or a complex object

Comment: @uk2k05 i have updated the question

Comment: @new_comer your $scope.notifications is an array, you're trying to access the userId without defining which member of the collection you're using. I'm refering to the line alert($scope.notifications.userId), you should do something like alert($scope.notifications[0].userId).

Answer (score 0):

You should do a **`ng-repeat`** if you want to access in HTML, or use **`angular.forEach`** if you want to access in controller.

```
angular.forEach($scope.notifications, function(value, key) {
  console.log(value.userId);
});
```

**EDIT**
Say you have $scope.userID and then you can get the UserDetails with the following line,

```
$scope.userDetails = $scope.notifications.filter(o=> o.userid == $scope.userID);
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker',[])
app.controller('MainCtrl',function($scope){
$scope.userID = '9e4e5627-8504-4035-9037-c56f9b5920cd';
   $scope.notifications = [{
  "id": 1,
  "commentid": "Otto",
  "groupid": 1,
  "postid": "osawbridge0@mysql.com",
  "status": "Male",
  "type": "Administrative Officer",
  "userid": "9e4e5627-8504-4035-9037-c56f9b5920cd"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "commentid": "Sayer",
  "groupid": 2,
  "postid": "ssowley1@lulu.com",
  "status": "Male",
  "type": "Chemical Engineer",
  "userid": "0f07bc0e-1385-4bb8-ac4b-9262039536f7"
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "commentid": "Analiese",
  "groupid": 3,
  "postid": "amabley2@umich.edu",
  "status": "Female",
  "type": "VP Sales",
  "userid": "28552fd8-1fb7-42e0-a0c3-d32f05389d25"
}];

$scope.userDetails = $scope.notifications.filter(o=> o.userid == $scope.userID);

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
   </head>
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h1> User Details </h1>
    <h3>  {{userDetails}} </h3>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, what i want is how to get the details of user using userId.
I tried it with different function by passing the userId to the function and get all the details associated with userId.

Comment: $scope.userDetails = $scope.notifications.filter(o=> o.userid == $scope.userID);
this is retrieving the user details  associated with the userid

Comment: $scope.userDetails = $scope.notifications.filter(o=> o.userid == $scope.userID);
I tried this, but i got only the above values.

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: the image i have attached in the question.
What I am trying to doing, is in $scope.notification: i have different attributes like commentid, postid, userid. Using the userid i am trying to get the picture, name, and other info about the particular user.

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript `filter` method to this

```
var userID = $scope.notifications.filter(o=>{
  if(o.hasOwnProperty("userId")){
    return o.userId;
  }
})
```